# Emacs + Mac OSX and changing default font

Tags: emacs, macos, emacs23

how I can change default font to Monaco with antialiasing on Emacs 23. Where I can find dedicated binary for Emacs 23.1 for cocoa with antialised font settings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the font faces via: `M-x customize-faces` and type `default` when prompted `Customize face (...):`  There's an option to `Save for Future Sessions` which will write to your `custom.el` file, so the face will be set next time you run Emacs.

There are two distributions which are popular

- [Carbon Emacs](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/unix_open_source/carbonemacspackage.html) (The Traditional)
- [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) (The more Mac like)

Both are excellent binary distributions.

Answer (score 15):

There is another question that deals with fonts on Emacs and Mac OS here: [How do I set fonts on Emacs for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132426/how-do-i-set-fonts-on-emacs-for-mac)

I found it easiest to add something like this to my init.el

```
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil
                :family "Inconsolata" :height 145 :weight 'normal)
```

Answer (score 7):

I grab my OS X Emacs binaries from http://atomized.org/wp-content/cocoa-emacs-nightly/.

You can find the settings for the default font in `M-x customize`, then once inside the customize menu, you follow this path: `-> Faces -> Basic Faces -> Default` .

Answer (score 2):

If you have xcode installed you can build emacs your self nothing extra needed, which uses anti aliased  monaco as the default font.

Comment: true, but that's how those nightlies are compiled. Who wants to spend time recompiling Emacs periodically when the nightlies are available for download?

It's just clear that the asker of the question isn't clear on where he needs to go to change the fonts, and that is useful info to have.