# How do I set fonts on Emacs for Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, fonts

I downloaded Carbon emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.35) from http://emacsformacosx.com/.  It defaults to using Monaco, and I would like to change it to use Inconsolata-dz.  So I added:

```
(set-default-font "-apple-Inconsolata-dz-medium-normal-normal-*-10-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")
```

to my ~/.emacs file.  However, after I restart, it is still Monaco.  It discovered that Option-T (or maybe Command-T) brings up a font dialog, and if I select Inconsolata-dz from that, it works great.  But if I restart, it is back to Monaco.  So I tried setting the font from the menu, and then going to Customize Faces and saving it, but still it does not work.  The interesting thing is that if I do M-x describe-font after changing the font from the Option-T dialog, it says -apple-Inconsolata-dz-medium-normal-normal-*-10-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1.

So it looks like Emacs is simply ignoring this font for some reason.  Why is that, and what can I do to get it to use this font?

Update:  I tried Donkopotamus and Joost Diepenaat's recommendations and they also did not work, although I ended up getting Times as my font, instead of Monaco.  However, they work great if I just use the Inconsolata (not Inconsolata-dz).  So I'm wondering if there is some problem with fonts with a dash in their name?

Update2:  Why is this off-topic?  The close message says "questions [should ...] relate to programming or software development in some way";  many developers use emacs, and getting settings right is important.  The top two entries on a search for "programming fonts" have a combined 150; so font configs seem to be important to programmers.  Anyway, if it is off-topic, where is the appropriate place to post it?

Answer (score 8):

I use plain Inconsolata. From my emacs.d/init.el:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "Inconsolata" :height (case system-type
                                                    ('gnu/linux 130)
                                                    ('darwin 145)) :weight 'normal)
```

If you're only running on OSX, you can simplify that to

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "Inconsolata" :height 145 :weight 'normal)
```

Comment: The value of `:height` is the font size in 1:10 pts. So for a 14.5 pt font, the value of `:height` should be 145. For a 13 pt font, the value of `:height` is 130, et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

I use Inconsolata.  In my .emacs I simply set the default font to Inconsolata using

```
; check if we're on OSX
(when (featurep 'ns-win)
  (custom-set-faces
   '(default ((t (:height 140 :width normal :family "Inconsolata")))))
  )
```

Comment: It seems that emacs don't display font with monospace when I use this.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behavior on Mac, and now I do this in my emacs init file:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :foundry "apple" :family "Anonymous_Pro")
```

That works nicely for me, but note that I'm using a newer (HEAD) version of Emacs. You would presumably need to use `"Inconsolata-dz"` as the value for `:family`.

Without this, new frames would always pop up using the system-wide default monospaced font (Monaco), which is likely what's happening for you.

P.S. Your Emacs version is a *Cocoa* Emacs, not a Carbon Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `.emacs` is being read in?  For example, are other things in there taking effect?

Assuming that is okay, I use this in my init file:

```
;; (insert "\n(set-default-font \"" (cdr (assoc 'font (frame-parameters))) "\")\n")
```

Note that it is intentionally commented out.  Now set your font using Command-T, then go to the end of the above line and do <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> .  It will insert a command to set your font to whatever it is now.  Save/exit/enter Emacs and you should have your font.